# SQL Query to list all empty colums in one Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm struggling to build a query to list all empty columns in one table.
Is there a simple function to do that, something like:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable' AND COLUMN IS NOT EMPTY
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I guess there is no `COLUMN` field in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

Comment: What do you mean by `empty`?

Comment: What do you mean as an empty column? Is it a column with NULL values in all rows?

Comment: hi, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build `Dynamic SQL`, but you can also do :

```
SELECT colname
FROM Mytable t CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES ('col1', col1), ('col2', col2),  . . .  ) tt (colname, val)
GROUP BY colname
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN val IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I need to perform this for my whole DB (100 tables, 100 columns per table) so the objective is not to list each column in all DB by hand. I will have a look at Dynamic SQL then.

Comment: @YoannG. . .  Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamic SQL here and iterate over each column from the query you gave.  But, we can just as easily use regular SQL:

```
SELECT
    REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(
        CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
             THEN 'col1,' ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN col2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
             THEN 'col2,' ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN col3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
             THEN 'col3,' ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN col4 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
             THEN 'col4' ELSE '' END), 1, 1, '')) AS empty_columns
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will give a look at Dynamic SQL then